# If a sports team is up $2-1$ in a best of $7$ series, what's the probability that they will win the series?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

Assuming that each team has an equal $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of winning each game, and the probability of winning each game is independent.

I solved this using a tree diagram, and got the answer of $\frac{11}{16}$, but I want to figure out a way of solving this without relying on a tree.

I tried diving this up to cases where the series ends in 2 games, 3 games and 4 games, but am having difficulty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An alternative to dividing this up into cases where the series ends in $2$ games, $3$ games and $4$ games, is to play all $4$ remaining games (some unnecessarily): this team need to win $2$, $3$ or $4$ of them to win the series

Comment: I checked that thread out, but the solution given uses a tree or assuming all of the remaining 4 games get played out. I'm trying to use cases where not all 4 games necessarily get played out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the winning team necessarily wins the last game of the series. So there are three cases to consider:

- The series ends in $5$ games. This occurs if the current leading team wins games $4$ and $5$, which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}$
- The series ends in $6$ games. Since they must win game $6$, they also must win exactly one of games $4,5$. The outcomes look like WLW, LWW. There are $2$, and each has probability $\frac{1}{8}$ so this outcome occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}$
- The series ends in $7$ games. Since they must win game $7$, they also must win exactly one of games $4,5,6$. The outcomes look like WLLW, LWLW, LLWW. There are $3$ outcomes and each has probability $\frac{1}{16}$ so this situation occurs with probability $\frac{3}{16}$

Therefore the answer is
$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{16}=\frac{11}{16}$$

Comment: Is there a way to calculate this with using combinations?

Comment: What do you mean by "combinations"? I simply wrote out all possible outcomes that satisfy the condition in your question.

Comment: I understand, but I'm required to put in combinations, such as 2C2.

Comment: I see. That wasn't included in your question so I took a different route. For future reference, if you need a question solved in a specific manner you should include that in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not sure how to get the denominators using combinations. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: For example, in the 7 game scenario, they must win exactly one of the three games 4,5,6. So there are $\binom{3}{1}$ games to choose for them to win

Comment: I understand that for that situation, there are 3C1 ways to choose the W in games 4,5,6, and then the two L's have to go in the remaining places. But how do you get 16 as the denominator?

Comment: Because there are 4 games and each can be decided in one of 2 ways. $2^4 = 16$

Comment: Oh, we can't use combinations for the denominator?

Comment: I guess you could write $\binom{2}{1}^{4}$ but that would be kind of weird. Usually the combinations contribute to the numerator in these types of problems

Answer (score 0):

You can take a Markov chain approach. The possible states that describe the series are of the form $(m,n)$, where $m$ is the number of games won so far by team A and $n$ is the number of games won so far by team B. In your example, the series is in state $(2,1)$.

Let $P(m,n)$ denote the probability that team A will win the series, given it is in state $(m,n)$. Let's consider your specific example of $(2,1)$. Two outcomes are possible starting from this state (each with probability ${1 \over 2}$. Team A can win game 4 and the series could go to state $(3,1)$ or Team B could win game 4 and the series could go the state $(2,2)$. You can express the probability relation as:

$$P(2,1) = {1 \over 2}P(3,1) + {1 \over 2}P(2,2)$$

By the same logic:
$$P(3,1) = {1 \over 2}(1) + {1 \over 2}P(3,2)$$
$$P(3,2) = {1 \over 2}(1) + {1 \over 2}P(3,3)$$
$$P(3,3) = {1 \over 2}(1) + {1 \over 2}(0)$$
$$P(2,2) = {1 \over 2}P(3,2) + {1 \over 2}P(2,3)$$
$$P(2,3) = {1 \over 2}P(3,3) + {1 \over 2}(0)$$

You have the necessary equations above to solve for $P(2,1)$ for the probability of winning from any state, for that matter.

Also, you can use matrix notation to express state transitions instead of the tedious equations I wrote above.